# Adding New OneToMany Associated Entity in Symfony 2.5 preUpdate Event Listener

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Using Symfony 2.5, the [Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate) says that the `preUpdate` event listener is the most restrictive. You can't just make a change to the entity, instead you have to use the special function:

```
$entity->setNewValue($fieldName, $value)
```

However, I have an entity `$view` which has an one to many associated entity `$routing`, and I have a special setter in my `$view` object that adds multiple routes:

```
class View { 

    protected $routing;

    public function getRouting() {
        return $this->routing;
    }

    public function addRouting(\Gutensite\CmsBundle\Entity\Routing\Routing $routing)
    {
        // Maintain Relationship
        $routing->setView($this);
        $this->routing[] = $routing;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

I do not have a `setRouting()` function in that entity, because instead I have an addRouting() because it is a multiple `oneToMany` association.

So... in my preUpdate event listener, how am I supposed to create a new "default" route, and add it to view, since the `$entity->setNewValue()` function won't exactly work on a collection, and evidently I can't just call `$view->addRouting($route)` (I tried that but nothing gets persisted to the database).

*Note: since 2.4 we should use the LifeCycleEventArgs instead of PreUpdateEventArgs ([evidently](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks-event-argument)).*

```
public function preUpdate(LifeCycleEventArgs $eventArgs) {

    $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
    $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();

    if($entity instanceof View) {
        if(!$entity->getRouting() || !$entity->getRouting()[0]) {
            $routing = new Routing();
            // simplified code to Set Friendly URL
            $routing->setFurl('Unknown-Friendly-URL-'.$entity->getId());
            // Set Default Values for Route
            $routing->setFlagPrimary(1);
            $routing->setTime(time());
            $routing->setTimeMod(time());
            $routing->setStatus(1);
            $routing->setView($entity);

            // Add the route to the View Entity
            $entity->addRouting($routing);

            // Recalculate Entity Changes (not working)
            $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
            // This doesn't work whether I compute the changesets for $entity (which is $view) 
            // or if I calculate changes for $entity->getRouting() (which is the new route I'm adding).
            $classMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
            // Recomputer Entire Change Set Because it's a New Record (I'm not sure this is necessary or not)
            $uow->computeChangeSet($classMetadata, $entity);
            // This doesn't work either
            $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($classMetadata, $entity);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should be using onFlush instead?

Answer (score 4):

I ended up just implementing this in an `onFlush` event. The `preUpdate` is too restrictive for my use case.  So that begs the question: **why use preUpdate when onFlush is more flexible?**

### Benefits of `preUpdate`

Insert a simple value to an entity, e.g.

```
$eventArgs->setNewValue('myField', $value);
```

You also have access to the entities old and new values (which is super useful for easily comparing WHICH fields changed, something I have needed before).

> This event has a powerful feature however, it is executed with a
>   PreUpdateEventArgs instance, which contains a reference to the
>   computed change-set of this entity. This means you have access to all
>   the fields that have changed for this entity with their old and new
>   value.
>   --[reference](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate)

NOTE: If you do use preUpdate, remember that you must use the `setNewValue()` syntax, not the normal setter for your entity. There is no need to recalculate the change set, and you also **[should NOT call persist](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate)**:

> Any calls to EntityManager#persist() or EntityManager#remove(), even
>   in combination with the UnitOfWork API are strongly discouraged and
>   don’t work as expected outside the flush operation.

### Problems with `preUpdate`

> Changes to associations of the updated entity are never allowed in
>   this event, since Doctrine cannot guarantee to correctly handle
>   referential integrity at this point of the flush operation.
>   --[reference](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate)

So if you need to update a child or the parent value (e.g. update the modification time of the parent), you can't do that within preUpdate because the `setNewValue` method is called on the eventArgs for the current entity, not on a specific entity.

Or if you need to add a collection, as in my question, you can't call custom setters like `addRouting` (for the reasons I mentioned). I suspect that means@RomaKliuchko's suggestion would not work.

*Please add other advantages and disadvantages.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to implement `setRouting(ArrayCollection $routing)` method, which will override existing collection and do like this:

```
$routings = $entity->getRouting();
// add entities to routing collection if needed
$eventArgs->setNewValue('routing', $routings);
```

Comment: I did not try to add a setRouting() setter on the View entity, and alias it to addRouting(). The mechanics of setNewValue() are a little too mysterious to me. 

I ended up using an `onFlush()` event, which is much more predictable and seems to be necessary for more complex updates, e.g. collections, or updating a parent entity (which doesn't seem possible from the $eventArgs method). 

In the future I will probably avoid using preUpdate, I don't see the benefit of it. If it's simple enough to do with an annotation on the entity, do it there. If it is too complex, preUpdate won't work anyway.